# career autocomplete fills in text box, but only first characters are stored

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, autocomplete

When using the auto-complete on careers.stackoverflow.com, only the characters I type are stored and displayed on saved document--not what the autocomplete seems to complete.  Fields effected:

- University
- Other: First Computer
- Other: Favorite Editor

Probably others too.  Details:

```
FF 3.5.3
OSX 10.6.1
```

Comment: +1 I saw this in the University field.

Comment: I had this happen to me as well, my favorite editor was ne.

Comment: @James McMahon, to be fair, ne is quite a nice editor anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this too, and I think I've figured out why.

The careers site appears to save fields as part of a blur event on the field.

What I imagine happens, is this:

- you type the first however many characters
- autocomplete dropdown appears
- you click the autocomplete dropdown
- blur event triggers on the input field, the content of the input field gets saved
- the content of the input field gets replaced from autocomplete.

Since another blur event doesn't get triggered on the field, the autocomplete data doesn't get saved.

The work-around seems to be not to use the mouse the select options from the autocomplete dropdown.

Comment: Nice investigative work - thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix was to have text inputs retain focus after the autocomplete selection; not the best solution, but it'll fire that blur again.